# 3-х уровневое меню на pdoMenu

Tags: modx, menu

заблудился в 3х соснах. В шаблоне всё красиво получилось, а вот в pdoMenu никак не могу корректно перенести.
Шаблон:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="dropdown menu-item">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Pages</a>
        <ul class="nav menu1">
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="index.html">Page_1</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-menu">
                    <li class="yamm-content">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                    <li><a href="#!">Item1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#!">Item2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#!">Item3</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="index.html">Page_2</a>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

делаю так:

```
[[pdoMenu?
                &level=`3`
                &parents=`4`
                &firstClass=`0`
                &lastClass=`0`
                &outerClass=`nav`
                &innerClass=`nav menu1`
                &parentClass=`dropdown`
                
                &tplInner=`@INLINE <ul[[+classes]]>[[+wrapper]]</ul>`
                &tplInnerRow=`@INLINE <li class="dropdown"><a href="[[+link]]" [[+attributes]]>[[+menutitle]]</a><ul class="dropdown-menu mega-menu"><li class="yamm-content"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-4"><ul class="list-unstyled"><li><a href="[[+link]]" [[+attributes]]>[[+menutitle]]</a>[[+wrapper]]</li></ul></div></div></li></ul></li>`
                &tplParentRow=`@INLINE <li class="dropdown menu-item"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="[[+link]]" [[+attributes]]>[[+menutitle]]</a>[[+wrapper]]</li>`
            ]]
```

Но дублируются:

```
<li class="dropdown menu-item">
        <ul class="nav menu1">
```

Т.е. структура должна получиться:

```
<ul class="nav">    
    <li class="dropdown menu-item">
        <ul class="nav menu1">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-menu"><li class="yamm-content"></li>...
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>       
</ul>
```

а получается:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="dropdown menu-item">
        <ul class="nav menu1">
            <li class="dropdown menu-item">
                <ul class="nav menu1">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-menu"><li class="yamm-content"></li>...
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Вопрос — подскажите, где ошибся?

Answer (score 0):

да уж, оказалось всё проще -запутался не в меню, а в уровнях ресурсов )) а здесь всё правильно